# Using JQuery to wrap and append alternative html content depending on the type of class that the child image element has

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Using JQuery to wrap and append alternative html content depending on the type of class that the child image element has

When an image is centred or floated left or right within a WordPress post, the core WordPress files add class names such as aligncenter, alignleft or alignright to the img tag. This is so that css can be used to float the image left or right or maintain it in the centre depending on what the administrator chooses.

I have choosen to wrap my post images as detailed below to provide an interesting rollover effect to the whole image when I hover over it.

The alignleft and alignright class subsequently do nothing to the image since the figure html element now has priority over how the image is styled and is not floated. What I would like to do is to use JQuery to add a class to the figure image depending on what the alignment class is on the child element, the image.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I could do to make this script work? Here is the end html code

```
    <a href="http://www.jonathanbeech.dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ACF-flexible-content-page.jpg" class="prettyPhoto" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">
    <figure class="fignoFloat">
        <div class="overlayArticle">
        <img class="wp-image-509 aligncenter" alt="ACF flexible content page" src="http://www.jonathanbeech.dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ACF-flexible-content-page-420x350.jpg" class="prettyPhoto">
        <span></span>
        </div>
    </figure>
    </a>
```

I used Jquery originally to wrap and append html code to the img as follows which works fine:

```
jQuery(function ($) {   
    $(".entry a.prettyPhoto img").wrap('<figure class="fignoFloat"><div class="overlayArticle"></div></figure>');
    $(".overlayArticle").append('<span></span>')
});
```

I tried a conditional statement (see below) but this failed? The altered html is not applied when the alignleft class is applied to the image:

```
$(function() {
    if ($(".entry a.prettyPhoto img").hasClass("aligncenter")) {
        $(".entry a.prettyPhoto img").wrap('<figure class="fignoFloat"><div class="overlayArticle"></div></figure>');  
        $(".overlayArticle").append('<span></span>');
    }
    else if ($(".entry a.prettyPhoto img").hasClass("alignleft")) {
        $(".entry a.prettyPhoto img").wrap('<figure><div class="overlayArticle"></div></figure>');
        $(".overlayArticle").append('<span></span>');
    }   
});
```

Comment: I believe if any `$(".entry a.prettyPhoto img")` does not have the aligncenter class, the if statement will return false, same with the else if, so basically none of those if will run. You can use https://api.jquery.com/each/ and apply the if inside the function to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".entry a.prettyPhoto img").each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.hasClass("aligncenter")) {
        self.wrap('<figure class="fignoFloat"><div class="overlayArticle"></div></figure>');  
        self.closest('.overlayArticle').append('<span></span>');
    }
    else if (self.hasClass("alignleft")) {
        self.wrap('<figure><div class="overlayArticle"></div></figure>');  
        self.closest('.overlayArticle').append('<span></span>');
    }   

});
```

This will iterate through all of prettyPhoto images and check the condition for each photo and apply whatever is needed.

The code you had before does not run because `$(".entry a.prettyPhoto img")` will select all of the img with class aligncenter and alignleft. If any of the img does not have aligncenter it will return false and same for the left one. So both of your if statement does not run since there are aligncenter and alignleft elements in prettyPhoto images

Actually a better way is

```
$(".entry a.prettyPhoto img.aligncenter").wrap('<figure class="fignoFloat"><div class="overlayArticle"></div></figure>');
$(".entry a.prettyPhoto img.alignleft").wrap('<figure><div class="overlayArticle"></div></figure>');  

$(".entry a.prettyPhoto .overlayArticle").append('<span></span>');
```

target the aligncenter ones, wrap it, target the alignleft ones then wrap it. Finally attaching the span to all prettyPhoto assuming prettyphoto will always have aligncenter OR alignleft class

Comment: Thankyou for your efforts, it appears the code still doesn't work. Maybe I could try posting it on jsfiddle? @Huangism

Comment: @JonathanBeech yea post it on a fiddle

Comment: @JonathanBeech I updated my answer, I forgot you wrapped the divs so the .parent will not work. I changed it to closest so it targets the correct element

Comment: Very odd @Huangism it seems to work ok on fiddle when the image is inspected not sure why it fails on my site?
http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Beech/eg278/

Comment: Thats great @Huangism much appreciated, I must make a mental note to learn more JQuery